# What is a lamprey's tongue derived from?

Tags: ichthyology

Tetrapods have tongues derived from the 2nd gill arch and nearby muscles. Lampreys are not tetrapods, and lack jaws, yet they have a tongue. What structure was this tongue adapted from?

Comment: Are tongues older than jaws? Because jawed fish came from jawless fish. Could have the same origin.

Comment: the tetrapod jaw is just the first gill arch.

Answer (score 2):

the "tongue" is just the bottom of the throat. Its not related to the tetrapod tongue nor are their "teeth" related to tetrapod teeth.

https://www.nature.com/articles/nature11794